# Entity manager - "cloud ready", "graph", "self validating"

Tags: java, entity

I'm looking for an "entity manager" with the following features (see list).

It seems strange to me that there are so many software projects that, in their core, are UI and business rules over a clever entity management, but I haven't seen a single entity management system that is "the" standard.
Oh, I've seen a few, but none of them come close to the list of features below. Most notably, cascades and validations are often missing from the core, horizontal scaling and cache invalidation are usually left as an "exercise to the student" and the graph nature is usually constrained to parent/child or, if you're lucky, to DAGs (directed acylic graphs).

Is there something clever that I'm missing? Or am I doomed to write this thing on my own - just like everyone else (and probably settle for less than optimal because of time constraints)?

Here's the list of features that, at least by my feeling, must be baked into the "core" of the entity management in order to really work well:

1. Graph based: Relations are a first level citizen, multiple relations between two nodes (labeled graph), can compute spanning trees and closures.
2. DB bound - or rather, not memory bound. Can hold caches in memory, but must be able to contain 100m entities and relations with ease.
3. Horizontal scaling - which means it knows how to access the DB from multiple app servers, use locking (optimistic or pessimistic) and invalidate caches on updates from another app server.
4. Support transactional work - either by collection the transaction in memory or in DB.
5. Support plug-able business rules cascades (e.g. if A is changed, then B must be changed as well) in the scope of a single transaction
6. Support plug-able validation (e.g. A cannot be removed if B exists).
7. Support plug-able authorization (e.g. user U1 cannot change A / user U1 cannot change A because this will cause B to change [cascade] and user U1 cannot change B).
8. Emit change event / maintain changes log (e.g. so workflows can be initiated after change).
9. Meta-data, if exists, should be configurable by "Data" and not by code.
10. No downtime upgrade ("cloud-ready", right?)
11. Pure Java.

Comment: Were You find a suitable framework? I need the same too, but nothing found. I made a simple JavaEE CRUD app to manage a ready JPA tree and still think about dynamic entity classes generation.

Comment: @ArchiMage - I wasn't able to find a framework. Instead we've opted to develop something on our own. On the other hand, some of the requirement have changed quite a bit, so it might not a true test case anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used this - but from what I have read [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) probably fits all your requirements

Comment: We're currently studying neo4j for future use, and it seems one of the most suitable database for your requirements, indeed. Even if I may have some reserve on the transaction point (you will never find something that is super-available, super-consistent and super-tolerant - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem )

Comment: I've researched neo4j. Indeed, it looks similar to what I need (though lacking quite a lot of features I'll need to build on top of it). However, I haven't seen any mention of multiple neo4j servers working over the same database (as in RAC). How can I horizontally scale this? Or make it highly available?

Comment: Sorry - neo4j does support HA by cluster-wide replication and channeling all writes through a single sever. However, it doesn't support sharding.